# The first item in a list-expansion cannot be null

Tags: c#, .net, dapper, executescalar, notsupportedexception

I am getting the error for **The first item in a list-expansion cannot be null** in the below mentioned code statement-

```
count += await connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>(sqlCount, parameters);
```

Below are the error details-
System.NotSupportedException at Dapper.SqlMapper.PackListParameters
outerMessage - The first item in a list-expansion cannot be null

Here is the complete code-

```
var sqlCount = @"
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT b.Id)
FROM DNs as b
INNER JOIN VProducts AS v
    ON v.Id = b.VId
INNER JOIN Data AS d
    ON b.VId = d.VId
        AND b.Id IN (d.ME)
WHERE v.Id = @Id
    AND v.xyz IN @xyzs
    AND (@Number IS NULL OR b.Number = @Number)
    AND (@Type IS NULL OR b.Type = @Type)
    AND (@StartDate IS NULL OR b.DeliveryDate >= @StartDate)
    AND (@EndDate IS NULL OR b.DeliveryDate <= @EndDate)
    AND (DeliveryDate IS NOT NULL OR @Number IS NOT NULL);";
int count = 0;
int result = 0;
using var connection = _dbHelper.GetOpenConnection();
for (int i = 0; i <= xyzs.Count / 2000; i++)
{
    var parameters = new
    {
        @Id = id,
                @xyz = xyzs.Skip(i).Take(2000),
                @Number = Number,
                @Type = Type,
                @StartDate = startDate?.ToUniversalTime(),
                @EndDate = endDate?.ToUniversalTime()
        };
    count += await connection.ExecuteScalarAsync<int>(sqlCount, parameters);
}
```

I am not able to find out much details about this kind of error. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Note the [@ acts as an escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim) for identifiers that conflict with C# keywords. It is not part of the identifier name. So, it you drop all the `@` in your anonymous type declaration, it will work just the same.

Answer (score 4):

This is caused by a `null` value in the @xyzs parameter. When Dapper attempts to expand that to a sql "in" clause it fails.

Try removing null from xyzs collection when setting your parameters:

```
@xyzs = xyzs.Skip(i).Take(2000).Where(x => x != null),
```

If you actually want records where `v.xyz is null` you will want to add that as another clause as well.